# Mac alias to go to folder and run rails server -- same command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal

Is it possible to go to a rails project folder and run the rails server in one alias on Mac OS X terminal?

Comment: Yeah you can create the alias command `alias MY_NEW_COMMAND "cd PROJECT_PATH && rails s"`

Comment: Figured it out but thanks anyway :)

Comment: can you please vote my post I have made my comments into post can yo u please accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can create the alias command `alias MY_NEW_COMMAND "cd PROJECT_PATH && rails s"`